# Adding icon to .exe

Tags: c++, windows, icons

Hi people I been trying to do this the whole night, can somebody help me/guide me on this.

Details:

- Not Visual Studio (using [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)).
- I'm using A lightweight IDE, and projects option is not available.
- Is for the .exe file output.

Please give me some guidance on this.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are using Visual Studio since you are talking about Windows.

First go to "Resource View" (from menu: View → Other Window → Resource View). Then in "Resource View" navigate through resources, if any. If there is already a resource of Icon type, added by Visual Studio, then open and edit it. Otherwise right-click and select Add Resource, and then add a new icon.

Recompile your project and see if change takes effect.

Second way:

Use [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381033%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your resource script to choose your icon file.

Comment: Like creating a file with the configuration, I'm sorry I'm not an expert on this matter.

Comment: Visual Studio is far from lightweight

Comment: ok Asumming this. I have a hpp file containing this:                          #define Myicon "../Iconos/cesitar.bmp"
And my main.cpp Icludes it but I compile, build and the icon still the same.

Comment: @Leandro: That would really depend if the code uses that Macro to pick up the icon file, which cannot be said unless we see the code, to give it a hot make sure you cleanup all the binaries and make sure the fle exists in the said locaion before you compile.

Comment: @Leandro: You can't add icons with `#define`.

Comment: Its kinda hard since Im not using any Microsoft IDE.... I'm using Geany, IDK if there is possible to make a .hpp resource file or to make this other way.

Answer (score 7):

I use [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) for such tasks. This will add an existing icon to an EXE; you'll need another tool to make the actual icon.

Comment: Sure but seems like my application doesnt have any source code

Comment: Resource Hacker works on the raw executable; you don't need source code.

Comment: It opens it but It doesnt find any inside

Comment: So? Your question was to _add_ an icon, not to change one.

Comment: Lol yes bro too bad I been banned from asking new questions but anyway Thx i added via resources.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [resource compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) rc.exe. You will also need to create a .rc file listing the resource (your icon). On compilation with rc.exe, you will get a .res file which should be passed to the linker.